# jQuery table sorter issues

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

table sorter is not working in Chrome, text 
i have a html table

```
<table id="DataTable" class="dms-table-data" border="1">                      <thead>
        <tr>
             <th id='textA'>
             <input type="text" name="name1"><br> // textbox
             </th>
             <th id='textB'><th>         
             <input type="text" name="name2"><br> // autofill
             </th>
             <th id='textC'><th>         
             <input type="text" name="name3"><br> // dropdown
             </th>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
     ......
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

i have used jquery.tablesorter.js to sort.

I'm getting issue in only Chrome,IE11 is working fine. i have dropdown,autofill textbox in thead columns.i can edit,select from list in IE11, but chrome is disabled dropdown list, autofill & can't type anything in  text box.

if i remove this jquery.tablesorter.js, its working fine in  Chrome w/o sorting.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/theme.default.css">
<!-- load jQuery and tablesorter scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>


$(function(){
  $("#myTable").tablesorter({ sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]] });
});
```

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) recreating the problem

Comment: can refer this [http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/2434/]

Answer (score 0):

You have defined for headers 3,2,1 `{filter: false}`. So the filters are disabled.

Change:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
sortList    : [[0, 0]],
        headers: {
            3: { filter: false }, 
            2: { filter: false }, 
            1: { filter: false } 
        },
        widthFixed : true,
        widgets: ["filter"],
        cssInfoBlock : "tablesorter-no-sort",       
        widgetOptions : {
            filter_external : '.search',
            filter_reset: '.reset',
            filter_columnFilters: true,
            filter_functions : {
                0 : true                
            }
        }
});
```

To:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
sortList    : [[0, 0]],
        headers: {},
        widthFixed : true,
        widgets: ["filter"],
        cssInfoBlock : "tablesorter-no-sort",       
        widgetOptions : {
            filter_external : '.search',
            filter_reset: '.reset',
            filter_columnFilters: true,
            filter_functions : {
                0 : true                
            }
        }
});
```

And it works.

Comment: Noy, i removed the "filter: false" from 3,2,1.in Chrome its not working. 
the given example is working in  ie11,(removing filter: false) in chrome drop down is fixed. drop down is not showing any data